# hive2.1.1 select statement is correct,but create table as select ... statement occurred error

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have this T-SQL query:

```
drop table if exists `xuzhiguo`.`not_arrived_dest_port_20210118_03`;

create table `xuzhiguo`.`not_arrived_dest_port_20210118_03` 
row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' as

select t1.mmsi,t1.utc,t1.lon,t1.lat,t1.planarrivedtime,t1.updatetime,t1.dest,
       from_unixtime(cast(t2.utc1 as bigint),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as arrivedporttime
from `xuzhiguo`.`not_arrived_dest_port_20201230_03` t1 
      join ais_data.yihailan_guakao11 t2 on t1.mmsi=t2.mmsi 
where from_unixtime(cast(t2.utc1 as bigint),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')<='2019-11-21 15:24:50'
  and from_unixtime(cast(t2.utc1 as bigint),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')>= from_unixtime(cast(unix_timestamp(t1.planarrivedtime) as bigint)-24*60*60,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
  and from_unixtime(cast(t2.utc1 as bigint),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')<= from_unixtime(cast(unix_timestamp(t1.planarrivedtime) as bigint)+24*60*60,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

When I execute the select statement, I can get the  correct result ,but when I add create table statement before the select statement, it occurred error

> [40000] [42000]: Error while compiling statement: FAILED:
> SemanticException Line 0:-1 Both left and right aliases encountered in
> JOIN ''yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss''

It worked before the last week, last week I found this error.

Any help?

Comment: Caused by the argument hive.cbo.enable=true